# Ionic PWA with capacitor

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

I am building a Ionic PWA. I don't want to generate the APK file so I add my app to homescreen. I want to open the device camera and save the photos captured in my device by creating a folder. I tried to access the `https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem` api to create a folder in the device directory and then save captured photos in it.

But I am getting this error: `FileSystem doesnot have web implementation`. Does the file system api works only if I generate a APK file or is there any plans in future to support for web?

Comment: Yes, filesystem API dosen't works with browser . You need to build android apk to access and use filesystem.

Comment: @AtulSharma We have waited so long for this capacitor because we don't want to deploy our app in playstore. So as the ionic team said we thought we can use the capacitor plugin api to access native functionality in web also. Do you think the implementation of filesystem api for web will be supported in future or it should be used Only for APK's?

Comment: Chances are very less, that browser will support these API's directly. Browser can only push files to be downloaded, to default directory. Most library endpoints are exposed by the wrapper and not the actual browser.

Comment: I am curious to know if capacitor only support APK's then it is not different than cordova which also used to work only on APK's. Then does the present version of Capacitor just elimates the use of cordova and support the native features only on Apks?

Comment: Its just like Ionic team started using their own product instead of Cordova, though both did the same thing. `Capacitor is a spiritual successor to Apache Cordova and Adobe PhoneGap, with inspiration from other popular cross-platform tools like React Native and Turbolinks, but focused entirely on enabling modern web apps to run on all major platforms with ease.` -- from IONIC website

Answer (score 4):

The Filesystem API has now been implemented. The Capacitor Filesystem plugin has a web implementation, based on IndexedDB.

See the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/filesystem/filesystem/src/web.ts

Comment: It does use IndexDB for PWA.  As of 10-2020, the source moved here:  https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/filesystem/filesystem/src/web.ts

Comment: As of 2021-11, the location is here: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/main/filesystem/src/web.ts

Answer (score -1):

The Filesystem API doesn't have a web implementation because you can't access the filesystem in browsers for security reasons. Accessing the filesystem is only possible for native devices i.e Android and iOS and Electron. So yes; you need to add an Android/iOS target and build a native application if you want to access the Filesystem.

Comment: And yet, on the Capacitor page for Filesystem, it shows it works (or will work) with pwa
ios
android
electron